# aircrack-ng shows non-existent ESSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, aircrack-ng

When I use `aircrack-ng dump-file`, I get a non-existent ESSID and can capture over 130,000 IVs, for example:

```
#  BSSID              ESSID                     Encryption

3  00:25:7B:4C:32:17  sanws                     WEP (137042 IVs)
```

Then if I try to crack this ESSID, it shows as cracked:

```
Attack will be restarted every 5000 captured ivs.
Starting PTW attack with 137042 ivs.
                 KEY FOUND! [ 73:61:6E:77:73 ] (ASCII: sanws )
Decrypted correctly: 100%
```

So the key is the same as the ESSID. And most important, the ESSID does not exist.

Why does this non-existent ESSID appear? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say the ESSID does not exist? Are you sure it's not just a "hidden" (non-broadcast) SSID?

That BSSID's OUI (00:25:7B) is registered to:

```
STJ ELECTRONICS PVT LTD
X-24 OKHLA INDUSTRIAL AREA
PHASE - 2
NEW DELHI DELHI 110 020
INDIA
```

Which appears to be these guys: [saviorstj.com](http://www.saviorstj.com/)

Any chance you have a fingerprint scanner or access card reader or similar equipment near you? Maybe one that publishes a closed/hidden/non-broadcast SSID by default for easy setup?

Comment: So the ESSID is `sanws ` and password is `73616E7773` which is the hex of `sanws`? I tried to join this Network using Mac OS X's `Join another network`, and it says not found. How can I test if this ESSID exists or not? How can I join that since I have got the key?

Comment: @Sato It's hard to know what's really going on without an 802.11 monitor mode packet trace. This thing could be sending Beacons but not responding to Probe Requests, which could cause it to be visible to tools that do passive scans, but not active scans (and a Mac doing a join usually does an active scan).